# Sending iOS Push Notifications using Django: HTTP/2-based APNs provider API and binary protocol

Tags: ios, django, push-notification, django-push-notifications

We need to send iOS push notifications using our Django based backend. Currently, we use this library https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications for sending notifications. Recently, received this mail from Apple Developers.

> The HTTP/2‑based Apple Push Notification service (APNs) provider API
> lets you take advantage of great features, such as authentication with
> a JSON Web Token, improved error messaging, and per‑notification
> feedback. If you still send push notifications with the legacy binary
> protocol, make sure to upgrade to the APNs provider API as soon as
> possible. APNs will no longer support the legacy binary protocol after
> March 31, 2021.

I saw that this library uses `apns2` (https://pypi.org/project/apns2/) for sending push notifications on iOS and that uses HTTP/2 protocol for sending notifications. **So, this library can continue to be used for sending iOS notifications right?** Can anybody clarify that for me? Also, it would be great if someone could explain the **meaning of legacy binary protocol**, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting the question here, I had also raised Github Issue on Django-Push-Notifications Repository.

I have got a reply from maintainers and it looks like we would be able to continue using this library. Posting his reply here,

> For what I understand this should not be an issue nor for this package
> nor for apns2 (which is used to send Apple-Push-Notifications).
>
> Apple is dismantling the legacy binary protocol (which was announced
> on October 9 2020) in favor of the HTTP one. However since apns2
> implements the latter this would not be an issue here since it already
> uses the preferred protocol.
>
> For the record: here is the specification of the legacy binary
> protocol for APNS.

https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications/issues/601#issuecomment-793489138